# Module not found: Can't resolve 'axios'

Tags: reactjs, npm, axios

I get this error.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/DataFetching.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'axios'
```

But when I look in packet.json i get this image

https://prnt.sc/1v77tyj

I already tried `npm install axios` and it didn't work. I look at other questions on stack and it didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my files.

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import DataFetching from './components/DataFetching';




function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <DataFetching />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

DataFetching.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

function DataFetching() {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res)
            setPosts(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataFetching
```

Edit: I made it work and this is how.

```
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: Did you try to remove node_modules and install everything from scratch? Also make sure it's installed in node_modules

Comment: Also, you can check whether the package is correctly installed by running `npm ls axios` It should give the version if it's correctly installed.

Comment: Likely unrelated as npm seems to be back up, but earlier today it was completely offline for a little while: https://status.npmjs.org/.

Comment: I tried your way. https://prnt.sc/1v7chfg Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

tried sandbox by the given code, the code has no issue, I am able to see the results on the page

Working Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-paper-rsz0n

Some time back npm as down if you have tried to install the module that time Axios might have not installed properoperly

you can check the npm status here:  https://status.npmjs.org/

delete node_mobules and try installing once again.

Comment: I did delete node_modules and reinstall them with npm install. Still the same.

Comment: as a quick fix, you can install Axios globally and try .? by doing npm install axios -g

Comment: It works now. I updated `npm with npm install -g npm` and it works. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a minor error. I did this and it resolved for me.

```
npm install -g npm
```

There were problems further but at least got rid of this error.